# Three table joins does not yield correct result upon GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables viz. actions, sources, and visits with some sample data given below:

**1. actions:**

[image]

**2. sources:**

[image]

**3. visits:**

[image]

Now, we want to know the number of visits through each source type and moreover also want to check how many visits are via contact and sale separately. The query still being used is:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.visits_id) AS visits, s.source_type AS source, 
SUM(a.action_contact) AS contact, SUM(a.action_sale) AS sale FROM visits AS v JOIN sources AS s ON v.source_id = s.source_id JOIN actions AS a ON s.source_id = a.source_id 
GROUP BY source ORDER BY visits DESC
```

**Output:**

[image]

So if you look into the output then you will find the number of visits are exactly equal to the sum of contact and sale for each row. So it seems to be OK. But if you sum up all the visits for all rows then it is not equal to 31. It is 47 in numbers which is not possible because we had only 31 visits in our visits table. Hence the output must not give us larger number of visits than that of visits table. This is the problem I have been facing in the query. How to bring up the correct result that must be in accordance to original tables?

**Updated table actions:**

[image]

Comment: While someone might be able to spot the issue at a glance, you would make things a lot easier for everyone if you posted actual data instead of screen shots. That woudl allow people to try the query for themselves.

Comment: You are absolutely right man! But oops I don't know how to post real MySQL data on STO.

Comment: Oh I just realized it is possible. I got it.

Comment: whatever query that you executed to produce those tables should be executed on the mysql consoe instead of a GUI

Comment: No problem, GUI also displays the sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're joining a many-to-many with actions to visits via sources. Ideally you would have a visit associated to each action, but you could also use the following:

```
SELECT s.source_type AS source
, count(v.visits_id) as visits
, ifnull((SELECT SUM(a1.action_contact) FROM actions a1 WHERE s.source_id = a1.source_id and a1.action_contact=1 
and a1.action_date between "2016-07-01 00:00:00" and "2016-07-31 23:59:59" -- filters date
),0) as contacts
, ifnull((SELECT SUM(a2.action_sale) FROM actions a2 WHERE s.source_id = a2.source_id and a2.action_sale=1 and a2.action_date between "2016-07-01 00:00:00" and "2016-07-31 23:59:59"),0) as sales
, ifnull((SELECT SUM(a3.order_value) FROM actions a3 WHERE s.source_id = a3.source_id and a3.action_date between "2016-07-01 00:00:00" and "2016-07-31 23:59:59"),0) as sum_of_order_values
FROM visits v 
JOIN sources s ON v.source_id = s.source_id 
WHERE v.visitor_date between "2016-07-01 00:00:00" and "2016-07-31 23:59:59"
GROUP BY source 
ORDER BY visits DESC
```

This will return one record per source, with the visits counted as per normal, but with contacts and sales summed as sub-queries so they're not being multiplied by the number of visits with the same source. If you're not familiar with many-to-many joins and the effect they have on the number of records (and therefore count and sum functions) you can see some examples here: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/

EDIT : I've just added on `sum_of_order_values` as a third subquery, which if your tables are big will be really slowing your query down. From the sound of your comment you're intending to add the visit_id to the actions table, and once you've done so you'll be able to just left join on each actions as a different table and this will greatly improve your query performance, provided you've indexed your columns correctly

EDIT AGAIN : I've just added the dates to the `WHERE` clauses, just be careful with timezones etc. You can "set" [session variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html) so you can update them all at once rather than individually. ie add

```
set @start_date = "2016-07-01 00:00:00";
set @end_date = "2016-07-31 23:59:59";
```

at the start of the query, then use `and a3.action_date between @start_date and @end_date` in the `WHERE` clauses

Comment: Didn't work! `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON s.source_id = a1.source_id and a1.action_contact=1) as contacts
, (SELECT SUM' at line 1 `

Comment: Oh sorry, stupid mistake. Edited so should now be right

Comment: oh so you had left out ifnull by mistake. Query now works, thanks!

Comment: Na, the ifnull is just for aesthetics. I had used ON rather than WHERE because I'd written the 2 tables as left joins first but realised that wouldnt work but forgot to change the join criteria

Comment: Oh i see. But now I am unable to fetch any other column of actions table.

Comment: You can by using sub-queries, it'll just slow your query down. Like I said in my answer, each action should really have a visit_id rather than a source_id, because then you could left join actions on visits where action_contact=1 to get contacts. Also consider using a EAV table if you expect there could be more actions as adding columns for new actions later could be problematic.

Comment: Oh you mean I need to restructure my actions table. It should have visit_id instead source_id. Ok. I can think of it lately. I have updated my actions table. Two new columns order_value and action_date are added there. I want to fetch order_value but don't have any idea how to do it? If I do, then the aggregate of all order_value = 1035 is getting out there.

Comment: I've updated the answer to return order_value as well

Comment: The result is not correct. Why did you take action_sale only and not consider action_contact?

Comment: My bad, I assumed all contacts would have an order_value of $0. I've edited the answer

Comment: OK great! Well are we able to filter the result on action_date? I mean get the visits only from within a date range.

Comment: yes, you can add `AND action_date BETWEEN "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" AND "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` to each of the subquery `WHERE` clauses, then also `WHERE visitor_date BETWEEN "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" AND "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` above `GROUP BY source`

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Now every `sum_of_order_values` becomes 0. Also what is `visitor_date`? Did you write wrong column name by mistake? Should it be `action_date`? But then it becomes unknown field name. Because there is no `a1 or a2 or a3`. Can you please write a complete query for me?